# Is this cron script correct?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

So I need cron to execute a script every 3 hours, on the hour starting at 3am.  So I need it to fire at these times:

> 0000 0300 0600 0900 1200 1500 1800 2100

Is this the correct way to execute this?

```
0 0 0..23/3 * * ?
```

Also, I'm running this through Quartz Scheduler and I'm wondering, even if the program goes down, when it starts back up, will it just run the script when it has it planned next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line you need:

```
 0 */03 * * * mycommand
```

Even if it doesn't work for whatever reason, it will still be run when it is next planned.